# Find index of string + integer in python

Tags: python, integer, find

I have a string "Something M6" and I want to find if "M6" is present in the string or not. The 6 in "M6" can be any integer. Is there any way to find it without using a regular expression or a for loop

Comment: Why not regular expression?

Comment: but will the M be constant

Comment: Why can't you use regular expression or for loop?

Comment: How about a while loop?

Comment: @Vignesh Yes The M will be constant.

Comment: Will M6 always be in the end of the string? I can see that most answers assume that. Could you e.g. encounter the string "Something M3 Molds"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> s = 'Something M6'
>>> 'M' in s and s[s.rfind('M') + 1].isdigit()                                                                                                                              
True                                                                                                                                                                       
>>> s = 'Something M1'
>>> 'M' in s and s[s.rfind('M') + 1].isdigit()                                                                                                                              
True                                                                                                                                                                       
>>> s = 'Something Mx'
>>> 'M' in s and s[s.rfind('M') + 1].isdigit()
False
```

This works for single digits. It looks for the last M in the string and checks if it's followed by a number.

If there are more than 1 digit following the M you can slice it to the end with a `:`.

```
>>> s = 'Something M123'
>>> 'M' in s and s[s.rfind('M') + 1:].isdigit()
True
```

Comment: but what if there were two M's

Comment: @VigneshKalai Yes it does, and if there are more than one M's, you can use `rfind`. I edited that in

Comment: @TimCastelijns can you please tell how can I get the index of that particular "M" if it is there?

Comment: @bazinga it's `s.find('M')` or rfind if you want to find the last M in the string

Answer (score 2):

```
myStr= "Something M6"
if 'M' in myStr:
    indexOfM = myStr.index('M')
    if myStr[indexOfM + 1].isdigit():
        print "Valid String."
    else :
        print "Invalid string."
else :
    print "Invalid string."
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess you can do it like this:

```
string = "Something M6"
if string.split(" ")[-1][0]=="M" and string.split(" ")[-1][1:].isdigit() :
   print True
```